# Ruby on Rails, after sign out, can still access to the page with user id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, authentication, registration, logout

I built login, sign up and sign out functions with Ruby on rails, and it seems that all of them work well.

When i user sign_up function to create a new user, a user_id will be created as well, and when i signed out, i can still get into the user page with the url which contains the user_id.

Is there anything wrong with my show function? How can i fix this issue please?

the `route.rb` is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'users/new'
  get 'home/index'

  resources :users
  resources :sessions
  resources :courses

  match '/about', to: 'home#about', via: 'get'
  match '/signup', to: 'users#new', via: 'get'
  match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new', via: 'get'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: 'delete'
  match '/main', to: 'users#show', via: 'get'
end
```

and the `users_controller.rb` is:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was sucessfully created!'
    else
      render action: "new"
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

the `sessions.controller.rb` is:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email], params[:session][:password])

    if user.nil?
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email or password."
      render :new
    else
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to signin_path
  end
end
```

the `sessions.helper.rb` is:

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def sign_out
    session[:user_id] = nil
    self.current_user = nil
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def deny_access
    redirect_to signin_path, :notice => "Please sign in first."
  end

end
```

for example, i create an account, and the user_id is 1, after i sign out, i can get into the account show page with url: `http://localhost:3000/users/1`
anything wrong with my work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a before_filter in your controller

```
# application_controller.rb
def check_if_logged_in
  deny_access unless signed_in?
end

# users_controller.rb
before_filter :check_if_logged_in, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :delete]
```

And also, is the `show` method supposed to show user by id or the profile page of the currently logged in user? If it is the latter case you need to modify it to

```
@user = User.find(current_user.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

IT doesn't look like you are restricting access to /users/show -- did you mean to?  It's loading the User object by ID and displaying it, just as it would if you went to any other `:resource` route.

Comment: I mean, after I logout, I can still enter into the user page without login, just enter the url with user_id

Comment: I think it's not secure, feels like the sign_out function is useless

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well for

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :show]
```

For `Index` and `Show` action user does not need to Authentication

**OR**  If you want to authenticate user for all actions

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

I am huge fan of **[Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)** for Login Model and for Admin Panel you can use **[CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)** or **[Active Admin](http://activeadmin.info/)**